# How to use jsPDF in Angular 7? Gets jspdf__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.jsPDF is not a constructor error

Tags: angular, jspdf

I am trying to use jsPDF in my Angular 7.1.3 project.

**My package.json is below (related parts):**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
```

**My component:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-html-pdf';

  @ViewChild('pdfTable') pdfTable: ElementRef;


  public downloadAsPDF() {
    const doc = new jsPDF();

    const specialElementHandlers = {
      '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
      }
    };

    const pdfTable = this.pdfTable.nativeElement;

    doc.fromHTML(pdfTable.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
      width: 190,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });

    doc.save('tableToPdf.pdf');
  }
}
```

There is no compile time error but running downloadAsPDF() function gives:

ERROR TypeError: "jspdf__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.jsPDF is not a constructor"

Answer (score 11):

The error is caused by the import statement

`import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';`

Change to:

`import jsPDF from 'jspdf';`

Comment: this works but why? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

im using angular 10 and this works: `const doc = new jspdf.jsPDF();`

Answer (score 0):

`import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';` works perfectly fine in angular 9. Try `import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';`

Answer (score 0):

install 1.4.1 version

```
 npm install jspdf@1.4.1
```

used import this :

```
import  jsPDF  from 'jspdf';
```

write below code :

```
const doc = new jsPDF();
var parser = new DOMParser();
var data = parser.parseFromString("<html><head></head><body>Hello world</body></html>", 'text/html');
doc.fromHTML(data.body.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
            width: 190,
});
doc.save('savePDF.pdf');
```